# Display content if url segment does not match a url_title

Tags: conditionals, embeds, url-title, segments

I am using pages to display content on a page called Speed Sales. I display the entry by checking for segment_2 and matching it to a channel entry basically. I need to display content in case someone spells the url wrong and it doesn't match a url_title in my speed_sales channel. Any ideas?

I'm assuming I might have to include a channel:entries tag with the channel="speed_sales" and check if segment_2 == a url_title for an entry, then display default content if it doesn't, but am unsure how to do this correctly.

EDIT:

I have updated my template to the following:

```
<article class="text-block">
        {exp:channel:entries channel="speed_sales" dynamic="no" url_title="{segment_2}"}
                {if url_title == "{segment_2}"}
                    <h2 class="heading1 excludestrip single left">{title}</h2>
                    {if lead_copy}<p class="lead">{lead_copy}</p>{/if}
                    {if subtitle}
                        <hr/>
                        <h3 class="excludestrip">{subtitle}</h3>
                    {/if}
                    {newsletter_copy}
                {/if}
                {if segment_2 == "" || no_results}
                    <h2 class="heading1 single">Speed Sales</h2>
                    <p class="lead">You may have reached this page in error (a typo in a link, or you backspaced the URL). Please choose a newsletter from below:</p>
                        {!-- {embed="speed_sales/.newsletter_list"} --}
                {/if}
        {/exp:channel:entries}
</article>
```

The reason I included the segment_2 check in my no_results conditional, is because it displays nothing in the no_results conditional (since there is no segment_2). The page url this would need to show up on is /speed_sales or anything under /speed_sales. What happens is everything works properly, but the if no_results conditional block displays multiple times instead of just once. It must be reading the amount of entries in the channel and repeating it that many times. I commented out the embedded list template to check, and it still repeats the block anyways.

Comment: I've noticed that the no_results conditional doesn't repeat, but if I want to place this block on the speed_sales page itself by using the `{if segment_2 == ""}` then it repeats that block. Any ideas on how to get around that?

Answer (score 2):

The `no_results` conditional should work, something like:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="speed_sales" dynamic="no" url_title="{embed:url_title}"}
    {if no_results}
        <!-- Content for no results -->
        {if:else}
        <!-- Otherwise ... -->
            <h2>{title}</h2>
            {if lead_copy}<p class="lead">{lead_copy}</p>{/if}
            {if subtitle}
                <hr/>
                <h3>{subtitle}</h3>
            {/if}
        {newsletter_copy}
    {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

(code untested)

See http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#if-no-results for more info.

Comment: This is what I would suggest but instead of using if:else just use a simple conditional {if no_results} some content {/if}.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot the no_results conditional. I will give this a shot and let you guys know.

Comment: I tried implementing something similar to this, and took this embed and put it in my main template, but the no_results block is being repeated multiple times inside the channel entries tag, instead of showing once.

Answer (score 0):

If there's no segment_2, the channel:entries variable pair will parse as:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="speed_sales" dynamic="no" url_title=""}
```

See? The [docs says](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#limit) that the default value of the `limit` parameter is 100. So, this loop will runs up to one hundred times!

My suggestion is, first, to put your code for no_results on a snippet and set its as, let's say, `snip_no_speed_sales`:

```
<h2 class="heading1 single">Speed Sales</h2>
<p class="lead">You may have reached this page in error (a typo in a link, or you backspaced the URL). Please choose a newsletter from below:</p>
```

Then, you need to separate your conditionals to avoid the parsing of `channel:entries` variable pair and to improve the performance.

```
<article class="text-block">
    {if segment_2}
    {exp:channel:entries channel="speed_sales" dynamic="no" url_title="{segment_2}"}
        <h2 class="heading1 excludestrip single left">{title}</h2>
        {if lead_copy}<p class="lead">{lead_copy}</p>{/if}
        {if subtitle}
            <hr/>
            <h3 class="excludestrip">{subtitle}</h3>
        {/if}
        {newsletter_copy}
        {if no_results}
            {snip_no_speed_sales}         
        {/if}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
    {/if}
    {if segment_2 == ''}
        {snip_no_speed_sales}
    {/if}
</article>
```

Comment: Ahh that looks like it might fix my dilemma, I'll try it out tomorrow thanks!